# baffling logback bug TimeBasedArchiveRemover$ArhiveRemoverRunnable

Tags: java, logging, logback, noclassdeffounderror

Logback 1.1.7

This was during a "production" run: stack trace from `Exception` (actually `NoClassDefFoundError` is an `Error`):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ch/qos/logback/core/rolling/helper/TimeBasedArchiveRemover$ArhiveRemoverRunnable
        at ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.helper.TimeBasedArchiveRemover.cleanAsynchronously(TimeBasedArchiveRemover.java:231)
        at ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy.rollover(TimeBasedRollingPolicy.java:178)
        at ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender.attemptRollover(RollingFileAppender.java:204)
        at ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender.rollover(RollingFileAppender.java:183)
        at ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender.subAppend(RollingFileAppender.java:224)
        at ch.qos.logback.core.OutputStreamAppender.append(OutputStreamAppender.java:100)
```

So I looked at the source: that class `ArhiveRemoverRunnable` does indeed exist in the .java file where it should have been instantiated on l. 231 (with that mis-spelling)...

Then I unpacked the executable jar (logback-core-1.1.7.jar): again, the file **TimeBasedArchiveRemover$ArhiveRemoverRunnable.class** exists in the package, as does file **TimeBasedArchiveRemover.class**.

This error is not going to happen that often: it is obviously when the "rolling" logger decides it's time to clean up the directory.

Anyone got any idea why this might happen? Troublingly I find no evidence of anyone else experiencing this...!

Answer (score 0):

**Potential workaround (pending):**

I thought the answer to this might be to extract the source files for this .jar, edit the offending class, compile and repackage as an executable jar, and then use instead of the downloaded jar.  In order to do this I started a new Gradle project in Eclipse, imported the entire source package, etc.  The thing compiles (builds) OK in Eclipse-with-Gradle, with no complaints of the "NoClassDef" type...

But I'm having difficulties actually producing this executable jar.  It'd be a nice thing to be able to accomplish: ability to tweak and test a downloaded dependency in some way (if really necessary).

**Current not so satisfactory workaround:**

In fact I have no need for a "time-based" archive remover.  I'm quite happy just having archives removed on the basis of the size of all the files in the logging directory.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28509787/logback-roll-only-on-file-size?rq=1) appears to solve this. However, logback is quite a beast: I'm not entirely sure: is "archive removal" the same thing as "rollover"?

If the `Error` occurs again, of course, I shall have to make a special utility method to log every `LOGGER.xxx` command within a `try...catch`.

Comment: Since no one is experiencing this problem, the assumption that it's a logback bug or a packaging problem is probably false. Repackaging is not going to help.

Comment: Any exception thrown by an appender is caught be that same appender and should not reach user code. However, this does not apply to errors such as NoClassDefFoundError a sub-class of java.lang.Error. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Error.html

Comment: I am getting The same error LogBack 1.1.11 as installed by vanilla Spring Frameworks maven, and using the LogBack config file illustrated at https://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html "Example: Sample configuration of a RollingFileAppender using a TimeBasedRollingPolicy"